# What is the smallest theory formulated in a given first-order language?

Tags: logic, symbolic-logic

I received an exercise question in my meta-logic course, which asks:

*"What is the smallest theory formulated in a given first-order language L? Provide an axiomatisation of this theory. What is the smallest set that axiomatises this theory?"*

**First, you need to tell me what the smallest theory is, that is, what's the smallest set of sentences of a first order language that constitutes a theory. Note that theories are closed under proof-theoretic consequence, that is, if a sentence follows from some members of the theory, then they should also be members of the theory.
Second you need to think about a set of sentences that axiomatises this theory, that is, a set of sentences from which all members of the theory follows. This can always be the theory itself. But is that the smallest axiomatisation possible? The answer is always no. So to give the smallest axiomatisation, the question you need to ask yourself is: what's the minimal set of sentences that you need as premises to derive all the members of the smallest theory?**

I am not very sure how to do this.

(EDITED)

Comment: It is hard to say without knowing what the "given first-order language L" is. Unless it refers to the trivial "theory" with an empty set of axioms.

Comment: I'm not very sure as well, but I think the question is asking what are is an axiom that holds for almost all theories?

Comment: None. There might be some "universal axioms" assumed in your course, but we wouldn't know without you telling us. If you are unsure ask the instructor.

Comment: Ok, I've asked my instructor and this is her clarification (See edits above)

Comment: I'd say it's an empty set of axioms, that is, a theory that includes L's syntactic rules and noting more. That would constitute a theory with 0 premises and 0 members. I think it qualifies...